# extract formatted input from file in scala

Tags: file, scala, input, io, extract

I'm working on a program that read a file, and from this file, I need to get the numbers in a specific order.

All the numbers are on the same line, and separated by a tabulation. Like in this example :

```
d       s       a       m
2       1       0       1
3       2       1       1
```

In C++, that should look like that :

```
unsigned d, s, a;
infile >> d >> s >> a;
```

But I'm new in Scala, so I have no idea how to do.

I'm using scala.io.Source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a string `str` containing whitespace-separated numbers (which you can get with `getLines()`), you can

```
val nums = str.
  split("\\s+").    // Splits at whitespace into an array of strings
  map(_.toInt)      // Converts all elements of array from String to Int
```

and then if you want to pull the first three out you can

```
val Array(d,s,a) = nums.take(3)
```

or

```
val (d,s,a) = (nums(0), nums(1), nums(2))
```

or various other things.

Comment: Thanks. It works when I try it in the Scala console, but I've got an exception during split when I try my program. I'll do more test.